# psycopg2 doesn't convert python array into a proper psql?

Tags: python, arrays, psycopg2

```
items= ['john','bushes']

cursor.mogrify("select something from table where something = ANY(%s)", (items,))
```

The above query produces something like ARRAY[a,b] which would take minutes to execute.

I was expecting the query to look like ('{a,b'}) in my psql query, which works million times faster.

Not sure how to make it produce the query from array in the right way.

I made a code below as a temporary solution, but obviously it opens it up for vulnerabilities:

```
items= ['john','bushes']

def proper_psycarr(arr):
    return ['{' + ','.join(arr) + '}']

cursor.mogrify("select something from table where something = ANY(%s)", proper_psycarr(items))
```

Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: And if you turn `items` into a `set` or a `tuple` instead?

Comment: You can probably also use `IN` instead of `= ANY` in your query.

Comment: I've just tried running `SELECT ARRAY['a','b'];` it a command prompt and it actually converts to curly braces array. However if I do this in a `WHERE` clause it breaks the query.